# OpenCV Python HoughLinesP gives error <unknown> is not numpy array

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I copied almost exactly the Hough Transform [documented here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) but using video capture instead. Here's my code in its entirety:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

    minLineLength = 100
    maxLineGap = 10

    if edges is not None and edges.size > 0:
        lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)

    frame.show()
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Using this code gives me the error

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "houghTransform.py", line 14, in <module>
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array
```

Why am I recieving this error?

Comment: what happens if you print edges above the hough lines call?

Comment: They're present. It turns out that HoughLinesP is incorrectly documented and minLineLength and maxLineGap caused the error. I removed those arguments and everything was fine, which for my example was totally OK.